# C# DataGridView wont display correct data from MySql database

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I just do not understand why my code dont work.
I have one `datagridview` and depending on the `combobox` item selected, and contents of some `textboxes` it will display a certain information from the database.

my code works perfectly fine and the datagridview displays information, except for this specific table information i want to show.
I actually checked if the mysql syntax works directly on MySql and it does, but on my c# application it displays the wrong information and i dont know why, please tell me if you see something wrong on my code, any suggestion or help is highly appreciated thanks.

```
MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection("SERVER = localhost; user id = root; password =; database = mpdb");
string selectQuery = "select a.empid as 'Employee ID', concat(b.eFirstName,' ',b.eMiddleName,' ',b.eLastName)as 'Full Name',a.CINd as 'Date IN',a.CINt as 'Time IN',a.COUTd as 'Date OUT',a.COUTt as 'Time OUT' from cicotbl as a Inner Join e_infotbl as b on a.empid = b.empid where a.CINd BETWEEN '" + this.TKRrDateFromtextBox.Text + "' AND '" + this.TKRrDateTotextBox.Text + "' AND b.empid LIKE('%" + this.TKRrNameIDtextBox.Text + "%')  or b.eFirstName LIKE('%" + this.TKRrNameIDtextBox.Text + "%') or b.eMiddleName LIKE('%" + this.TKRrNameIDtextBox.Text + "%') or b.eLastName LIKE('%" + this.TKRrNameIDtextBox.Text + "%') ; ";
DataTable table = new DataTable();
MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(selectQuery, myConnection);
adapter.Fill(table);
RUCGridView.DataSource = table;
myConnection.Close();
```

When ever i use this line, the table does no display the correct information

```
string selectQuery = "select a.empid as 'Employee ID', concat(b.eFirstName,' ',b.eMiddleName,' ',b.eLastName)as 'Full Name',a.CINd as 'Date IN',a.CINt as 'Time IN',a.COUTd as 'Date OUT',a.COUTt as 'Time OUT' from cicotbl as a Inner Join e_infotbl as b on a.empid = b.empid where a.CINd BETWEEN '" + this.TKRrDateFromtextBox.Text + "' AND '" + this.TKRrDateTotextBox.Text + "' AND b.empid LIKE('%" + this.TKRrNameIDtextBox.Text + "%')  or b.eFirstName LIKE('%" + this.TKRrNameIDtextBox.Text + "%') or b.eMiddleName LIKE('%" + this.TKRrNameIDtextBox.Text + "%') or b.eLastName LIKE('%" + this.TKRrNameIDtextBox.Text + "%') ; ";
```

but this line works though:

```
string selectQuery = "select a.empid as 'Employee ID', concat(b.eFirstName,' ',b.eMiddleName,' ',b.eLastName)as 'Full Name',a.CINd as 'Date IN',a.CINt as 'Time IN',a.COUTd as 'Date OUT',a.COUTt as 'Time OUT' from cicotbl as a Inner Join e_infotbl as b on a.empid = b.empid where b.empid LIKE('%" + this.TKRrNameIDtextBox.Text + "%')  or b.eFirstName LIKE('%" + this.TKRrNameIDtextBox.Text + "%') or b.eMiddleName LIKE('%" + this.TKRrNameIDtextBox.Text + "%') or b.eLastName LIKE('%" + this.TKRrNameIDtextBox.Text + "%'); ";
```

i want to know whats my mistake on the first one. thank you

Comment: This is the sort of problem that needs systematic debugging. If you're getting no rows in the table (before assigning it to the DataGrid) then it's not a DataGrid problem but a SQL problem. It looks like the BETWEEN clause is the problem, so concentrate on that. Does it need brackets around it? Are the text box strings in the right format for dates? Can you reduce the problem down to a single line that will be easier for people to look at?

Comment: Your first command contains dates filter so I think there is data type mismatch for date in your table and date that from textboxes. I suggest you double check the date  you saved in db and date you are passing from textboxes.

Comment: thank you guys for your suggestions. i just had to restart my visual studio now the code works. idk why its like that.